# Cordova/Phonegap FileTransfer.upload() error code = 1 (FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERR)

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, cordova-plugins

What's really confusing is when I capture the image with the phone camera, I use `FileTransfer.moveTo` and it sends the image to a specified folder on my SD card as desired. I also keep a list of image objects in `localStorage` that looks something like this:

```
[
Object
ean: "42208556"
image: "file:///storage/sdcard0/PhotoscanPhotos/d51b5b77-aab1-9947-096d-b0a92dfb87eafoto.jpg"
timestamp: 1396441761000
__proto__: Object
etc etc
```

As part of my app, i use the same image[i].image as src attribute to dynamically add images to a list and it works fine. However, using the same parameter for `FileTransfer.upload` gives me the above error.

My function is a near replica of the [API docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileUploadOptions) (Cordova 3.1). Code is as follows:

```
function uploadImagesAsJpegs(imageObject) {
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "file";
    options.fileName=imageObject.image.substr(imageObject.image.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    //alert(options.fileName);//debugging ............we're happy with this
    options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
    options.chunkedMode = true;

    var serverUrl = http://172.17.7.112/mylocalserver;


    var params = {};
    params.value1 = ean;
    params.value2 = imageObject.timestamp;

    options.params = params;

    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();

    //alert(encodeURI(serverURL));//debugging  ............we're happy with this
    //alert("image to upload is: " + imageObject.image);//debugging............we're happy with this
    fileTransfer.upload(imageObject.image, encodeURI(serverURL), onUploadSuccess, onUploadFail, options);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serverside script was wrong... naturally I should have figured that out given the obvious `FileTransferError.FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERR` error message.  Apologies for wasting everyone's time and thank you for making the effort.

Comment: can you please answer my question  . ?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23060307/phonegap-fileupload-java-server

Comment: The question has been a while, but i am just wondering, you are saying the Serverside was wrong but the File-transfer is calling error_code 1??? The file is not found but it was something on the server side? I am just confused, because i am having an error code 1 as well. But not sure what is causing it.

Comment: @John Hi John, I forgot the /s tag when I said Naturally... Unfortunately the code from phonegap wasn't of any help

Answer (score 8):

I believe setting `options.chunkedMode = false;` is solving most issues during file upload, maybe give it a try.

Comment: thanks, but I had previously tried that but to no avail. I should have mentioned it in my OP. Will edit same now.

Answer (score 3):

What I would try is: 
1. use [exclusive](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html) mode for upload (true at the end)

> fileTransfer.upload(imageObject.image, encodeURI(serverURL),
>   onUploadSuccess, onUploadFail, Options, true);

1. Try to move data first to the local store of device instead of working with SD Card storage. Perhaps it is a Case of permission and you just are able to upload from phone local storage.
2. Make sure the Image is not pending in another Image as imagesource and you have full Access to the data. Perhaps read&write is needed exclusive.

Comment: I've replaced the image src with something else just to see if displaying the image on the app was the problem but unfortunately no change. Regarding local storage, it would be far too small for my needs (capped at 5.7MB iirc). Tried exclusive mode also but to no avail. Thanks for the help though